# How to compute variable contributions to the principal axes for RDA in R? (Erorr: rdacca can't be handled by factoextra)

Tags: pca, vegan, rda, factoextra

```
data("mite") # Load mite species abundance data
data("mite.env") # Load envdata

# Hellinger transform the community data
mite.spe.hel <- decostand(mite, method = "hellinger")
mite.env <- mite.env[,1:2]
mite.env$SoilCont <- rnorm(70,5,2)
mite.env$SubsDens <- decostand(mite.env$SubsDens, method = "standardize")
mite.env$WatrCont <- decostand(mite.env$WatrCont, method = "standardize")
mite.env$SoilCont <- decostand(mite.env$SoilCont, method = "standardize")

mite.rda <- rda(mite.spe.hel ~ WatrCont + SubsDens + SoilCont, data = mite.env)
```

I want to compute variable contribution to each of the principal axis in the RDA. I found a similar computation using the `factoextra` [enter link description here](https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/factoextra/) package. This computes for PCA like this. How can I do this for the RDA analysis like above?

[image]

```
# Contributions of variables to RDA1
fviz_contrib(mite.rda, choice = "var", axes = 1, top = 10)

# Contributions of variables to RDA2
fviz_contrib(mite.rda, choice = "var", axes = 2, top = 10)
```

Error in .get_facto_class(X) :
An object of class : rdacca can't be handled by factoextra